# AS3 Adding same DisplayObject does not render TextField the second time

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, textfield

The problem I'm having is that I'm expecting multiple TextFields to appear, and I'm only seeing one appear. I've narrowed it down to this code. When I add the List element, I see an empty rectangle, with a rectangle of the exact size underneath as I would expect. The problem I see is that the TextField only appears in the second rectangle. If I add three elements, only the last is visualized.

The following code takes a list of DisplayObjects (currently two TextFields), iterates through the list, and creates a container Sprite for each. The container Sprite for each is offset by the height of each DisplayObject height, effectively creating a visual list. If the same TextField is used twice or more in the list, the TextField is only drawn in the last element. Each container Sprite contains a bounding box to indicate that it is present.

```
package
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

public class List extends Sprite
{
    private var data:Array=new Array;
    private var label:TextField= new TextField();

    public function List()
    {
        super();

        label.selectable=true;
        label.autoSize              = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        label.antiAliasType         = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        label.text                  = "Testing";
        data.push(label);
        data.push(label);

    }


    public function renderList():void{
        var height:int=0;
        for (var i:int=0; i< data.length; i++){
            //get current sprite in list
            var current:DisplayObject=data[i];

            //create new sprite to contain element of array
            var listItem:Sprite=new Sprite;
            listItem.addChild(current);

            //draw bounding rectangle for reference
            var rect:Rectangle=current.getBounds(this);
            listItem.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
            listItem.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            listItem.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
            listItem.graphics.endFill();

            //set height corresponding to bounds height
            listItem.y=height;

                            //calculate height for next item
            height=height + rect.height;

                            //add new list item 
            addChild(listItem);
        }
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not limited to TextField, but rather DisplayObject. A  DisplayObject has many DisplayObject. A DisplayObject does not 'has and belong to many' DisplayObject.

Since the DisplayObject can only have one parent referenced, when the same TextField is assigned a new parent, the original association between the first Sprite and the TextField is lost. The second Sprite becomes the parent of the TextField.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add the same TextField object as a child of two or more containers. you need to add `new TextField()` again somewhere in your code.

Like if you modify your constructor as below you will be able to see two TextFields

```
public function List()
    {
        super();

        label.selectable=true;
        label.autoSize              = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        label.antiAliasType         = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        label.text                  = "Testing 1";
        data.push(label);
        label = new TextField();
        label.selectable=true;
        label.autoSize              = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        label.antiAliasType         = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        label.text                  = "Testing 2";
        data.push(label);
    }
```

Comment: This is correct, though it is worth noting that he would lose the main reference to the first TextField and the only way to obtain it would be through the data array.

Comment: I just gave the hint what he is missing. I'm sorry for being a little lazy. Thanx for correcting me @Apocalyptic0n3